# Submitting form using selection value with form data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, forms, flask

I am new at this and trying to submit a basic form which has a dropdown list and 2 text fields. The lists value is the path of the flask route which needs to be submitted the data.

Depending on the item the user selects from the list, i would like to submit the form with data to that url, eg if user selects "a"  then i would like to submit form to http://url/url1. How can this be done?

```
  <form action="" class="form1" method="get">    
    <select class="form-control" id="function" name="cars">
          <option value="/url1">a</option>
          <option value="/url2">b</option>
          <option value="/url3">c</option>
        </select>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number1" value="">
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number2" value="">
      <input class="form-control" type="submit">
  </form>
```

I have python flask code on server :

```
@app.route("/url1")
def url1():
  num1=request.args.get('number1',default=-1,type=int)
  num2=request.args.get('number2',default=-1,type=int)
  evaluate the numbers and return render_template()

@app.route("/url2")
def url2():
  num1=request.args.get('number1',default=-1,type=int)
  num2=request.args.get('number2',default=-1,type=int)
  evaluate the numbers and return render_template()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question , you can solve it by jquery

code sample

```
$("#function").change(function() {
  var action = $(this).val();
  $("#form1").attr("action",action);
});
```

or

you can set a default action for the form and then in route do according to the selected value

Comment: would this then submit the values of these inputs also to http://url/a or http://url/b 
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number1" value="">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="number2" value="">

Comment: yes you will get the submitted values for each submit with different action url('/a','/b') by each control name as request parameter

Answer (score 0):

I used redirection in app.py to resolve this

```
<form action="/submit" class="form1" method="get">
```

and then

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET'] )
    def submit():
         num=request.args.get('number1',default=-1, type=int)
         return redirect(url_for('url1', m=num))

@app.route("/url1")
   def url1():
   evaluate the numbers and return render_template()
```